# How to calculate the complexity order of an optimization model?

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity

In some optimization problem it is stated that the complexity is ${\cal O}(n)$ or ${\cal O}(n^2)$. How is this calculated?

Comment: With a quick search on big O notation I found this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/big-o-notation-simple-explanation-examples-pamela-lovett

Answer (score 4):

I invite you to first check Wikipedia pages on [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) and [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Then, I would recommend you to study the [celebrated book "Introduction to Algorithms" written by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein](https://books.google.fr/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC). It will allow you to improve your knowledge and understanding of problem and algorithm theoretical complexity.

Comment: Of particular note (as mentioned early in the Wikipedia entry for computational complexity), the complexity bound is for a specific algorithm to solve a problem, not for the problem itself.